# How to get output from os.exec in go

Tags: go

I am trying to get the system output from the following code

```golang
cmdString := "lxc exec " + containerName + " -- ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1"
ip, err := exec.Command("bash", "-c", cmdString).Output()
fmt.Println(ip)
```

The above code should get the IP Address from an LXC Container.

The actual output from go is `[]`

I have also tried the following

```
ip, err := exec.Command("lxc", "exec ", containerName, " --", "ip addr show eth0", "|", "grep", "'inet\b'", "| awk '{print $2}'", "| cut -d/", "-f1").Output()
fmt.Println(ip)
```

I still get just `[]` as output

The correct output from the command line is like below

```bash
[root@localhost toolbox]# lxc exec simon -- ip addr show eth0 | grep 'inet\b' | awk '{print $2}' | cut -d/ -f1
10.183.201.38
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are passing the whole string as a single argument to the shell. Pass a `[]string` containing every separate argument in that string, including the redirections.

Comment: I just changed my code back to 
```ip, err := exec.Command("lxc", "exec ", containerName, " --", "ip addr show eth0", "|", "grep", "'inet\b'", "| awk '{print $2}'", "| cut -d/", "-f1").Output()
fmt.Println(ip)```
The result is still `[]`

Comment: That’s not a valid command. check the error or stderr if you don’t get the expected output

Comment: @JimB Do you mean the go code is not correct or the LXC command is not correct? The LXC command works fine at the command line. See the example at the bottom of my question.

Comment: I mean what you put in the comment is nonsensical. `" --"` is incorrectly quoted, `"|"` isn't an argument to `lcx`, it's a shell bultin, `"awk"` is a separate command,  etc. The first one looks like it should work in a shell at first glance, so check for errors or stderr to figure out what's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read this code then you can understand how to read result`s stdout

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/ls")
    buf := bytes.Buffer{}
    cmd.Stdout = &buf
    err := cmd.Run()

    fmt.Println(buf.String(), err)
}
```